# JSON adding style to text populated from WebFOCUS

Tags: jquery, json

I have a title on a page being populated from WebFOCUS.

```
h1 id="statementTitle"

$('#statementTitle').text( camelCase(demoJSON.cycle) + ' Value Report');

$('#statementTitle h1:contains('Report')').attr('style','color:#008000');
```

It's being populated, but I want to change the text color to part of it, and it's having issues with that. This is the first time I've worked with JSON.

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with JSON? `$('#statementTitle').text(...)` appears to be jQuery. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

What you have seems to be jQuery, so all you need is the [`.css`](https://api.jquery.com/css/) method and the right selector:

```
$('#statementTitle').css('color', '#008000');
```

> I'm looking for only part of the text to change color, the word 'Report'.

Wrap that word into its own element so that you can target it for style changes:

```
$('#statementTitle').html(
  camelCase(demoJSON.cycle) + ' Value <span class="callout">Report</span>'
);
```

And then:

```
$('#statementTitle .callout').css('color', '#008000');
```

Or better, just define the text color in CSS:

```
.callout {
  color: #008000;
}
```

Choose whatever class name fits for you.

Comment: Well that does work without errors. I'm looking for only part of the text to change color, the word 'Report'.

Comment: In that case you have to wrap the word into an element and target that element. Let me update my answer.